# Javascript make expanded paragraph autoclose

Tags: jquery, html, css

With `jQuery` for three sections of text, I want to show a paragraph of text when clicked that will hide when clicked again.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.section').hide();
$('h3').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(this).next().toggle();
}); //end toggle
});
```

Let's say you open one paragraph but then click another text and expand paragraph 2, I want the first paragraph you opened to automatically close when you click to expand another if that makes sense. How would I go on to do this?

Comment: assign a class name to all paragraphs - let's say "myClass". In click function first hide all with $(".myClass").toggleClass("close") or the actual method you use to collapse the paragraph then execute toggle on $(this) to expand it.

Comment: Can you provide some html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some html, but if I understand well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.section').hide();
$('h3').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(this).next().show();    //can use .slideDown()
     $(this).next().siblings('.section').hide();  //can use .slideUp()
}); //end toggle
});
```

this will work for :

```
<h3> heading section 1 </h3>
<div class="section">Section1</div>

<h3> heading section 2 </h3>
<div class="section">Section1</div>

<h3> heading section 3 </h3>
<div class="section">Section1</div>
```

Comment: Hello your code worked perfectly, just wondering if it is possible for paragraph to close when you click the text which expands it as well as when you open another paragraph.

Comment: @Krasimir Zarkov you can set the click event hander for .section

         `$('.section').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});`

Comment: that sort of worked. That made it so if you click the paragraph it closes it however I want it to work by clicking the text which causes the paragraph to apear. Here is a JS fiddle of what happens https://jsfiddle.net/xa011adf/

Comment: @Krasimir Zarkov oh I understand, here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xa011adf/2/

Comment: Thanks so much! Very pleased :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the beahaviour of an accordion - check out the following Bootstrap accordion from (http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click on the linked heading text to expand or collapse accordion panels.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```